# vmnet kernel module blacklist not working

Tags: debian, kernel-modules, vmware, module, vmware-workstation

I am trying to uninstall VMware Workstation completely to re-install it on my Debian system (due to an issue I faced regarding `vmnet`, preventing my NAT or bridge networks from attaching to my VMs). I ran `vmware-installer -u vmware-workstation` already but noticed the components remained:

```
# vmware-installer -t
Component Name                 Component Long Name                               Component Version   
============================== ================================================= ====================
vmware-installer               VMware Installer                                  3.1.0.22583795      
vmware-player-setup            VMware Player Setup                               17.5.0.22583795     
vmware-usbarbitrator           VMware USB Arbitrator                             20.10.0.22583795    
vmware-network-editor          VMware Network Editor                             17.5.0.22583795     
vmware-vmx                     VMware VMX                                        17.5.0.22583795     
vmware-tools-linuxPreGlibc25   VMware Tools for legacy Linux                     12.3.0.22583795     
vmware-tools-linux             VMware Tools for Linux                            12.3.0.22583795     
vmware-tools-netware           VMware Tools for NetWare                          12.3.0.22583795     
vmware-tools-solaris           VMware Tools for Solaris                          12.3.0.22583795     
vmware-tools-winPre2k          VMware Tools for Windows 95, 98, Me and NT        12.3.0.22583795     
vmware-tools-winPreVista       VMware Tools for Windows 2000, XP and Server 2003 12.3.0.22583795     
vmware-tools-windows           VMware Tools for Windows Vista or later           12.3.0.22583795     
vmware-player-app              VMware Player Application                         17.5.0.22583795     
vmware-ovftool                 VMware OVF Tool component for Linux               4.6.2.22583795      
vmware-network-editor-ui       VMware Network Editor User Interface              17.5.0.22583795     
vmware-vix-core                VMware VIX Core Library                           1.17.0.22583795     
vmware-vix-lib-Workstation1700 VMware VIX Workstation-17.0.0 Library             1.17.0.22583795     
vmware-vprobe                  VMware VProbes component for Linux                17.5.0.22583795
```

Referring to [this](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/38) KB, I tried to perform the uninstallation manually and tried to unload all the modules, but I got warnings that `vmnet` was not unloaded:

```
# /etc/init.d/vmware stop
Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
modprobe: FATAL: Module vmnet is in use.
rmmod: ERROR: Module vmnet is in use

# lsmod | grep vm
vmnet                  77824  1
vmw_vsock_vmci_transport    45056  0
vsock                  61440  1 vmw_vsock_vmci_transport
vmw_vmci              110592  1 vmw_vsock_vmci_transport
kvm_intel             413696  0
vmwgfx                438272  0
drm_ttm_helper         12288  1 vmwgfx
kvm                  1368064  1 kvm_intel
iwlmvm                589824  0
irqbypass              12288  1 kvm
mac80211             1396736  1 iwlmvm
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
iwlwifi               544768  1 iwlmvm
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
cfg80211             1339392  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
videobuf2_common       77824  4 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops
rfkill                 40960  7 iwlmvm,bluetooth,dell_laptop,cfg80211
nvme                   57344  3
nvme_core             196608  4 nvme
t10_pi                 20480  1 nvme_core
ttm                   106496  3 vmwgfx,drm_ttm_helper,i915
drm_kms_helper        270336  4 vmwgfx,drm_display_helper,nvidia_drm,i915
drm                   765952  27 vmwgfx,drm_kms_helper,drm_display_helper,nvidia,drm_buddy,drm_ttm_helper,nvidia_drm,i915,ttm
```

As a result, I can't completely remove the files etc. yet. I tried:

1. Adding `blacklist vmnet` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
2. Adding `modprobe.blacklist=vmnet` to `/etc/default/grub`

After doing those changes, I did run `sudo update-grub` and `sudo update-initramfs -u`, but upon restarting, the `vmnet` module was still loaded and I can't seem to get rid of it.

Any idea how I can get rid of `vmnet` module?